# Блокирует и не отправляются заявки

Tags: php, wordpress

По отправке форм, обращается программа через `ajax` к `php` файлу:

```
     $roistatData = array(
        'roistat' => isset($_COOKIE['roistat_visit']) ? $_COOKIE['roistat_visit'] : null,
        'key'     => 'MjM3MjM6MjY3NjU6ODhhM2EzMTczZDcxOTY0Zjg2YzQ2OTY2NTU1YWQ0ODc=',
        'title'   => 'Заказ оборудования',
        'comment' => 'С формы: ' . $_POST['form_title'] . '; Страница захвата: ' . $['url'] . '; Источник: {source}; UTM: {utmSource}/{utmMedium}/{utmCampaign}/{utmTerm}/{utmContent}',
        'name'    => $_POST['form_title'],
        'email'   => 'info@3agorodpro',
        'phone'   => $_POST['form_tel'],
        'is_need_callback' => '0',
        'fields'  => array(),
    );

    file_get_contents("https://cloud.roistat.com/api/proxy/1.0/leads/add?" . http_build_query($roistatData));

    echo true;
```

, где происходит отправка заявки в `roistat`.
Но отправка в roistat уже не работает, в логах вижу это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На почту не отправляется ничего, используется google tag manager + yandex analitics + roistat.

Comment: Что за файлы languages/dhdhdh.php backup/dhdhdh.php logs/dsusus.php? Вылечите сайт от вирусов для начала.

Comment: как можно его вылечить? Антивирусы не находят вирусов. На хостинге нашли подозрения на вирусы, но это в плагинах. Какие действия обычно предпринимают?

Comment: Сканирование плагином Wordfence

Comment: Стоял плагин sucuri-scanner, писал что вирусов нет. Сейчас никак в админку не могу войти. Переименовал плагины, переименовал htaccess. Страницу просто перезагружает. Подскажите что можно сделать?

Comment: Проблема вряд ли решается простым советом. Вариантов может быть много. Наймите специалиста.